# Using Controller Methods in View - Play Framework - Scala

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I have got to use the Play Framework on a Web-Project, in which i have to connect the view with the controller classes. Meaning, that i have to use methods, which were declared in the controllers (scala), in the view (scala.html).
I really don't know how. 
I've tried things like

```
     @controller.class.method()
```

but it didnt work.
I've looked it up, but found nothing, maybe because it's too simple, that anyone would ask about it..?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you give an example on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access reverse routes in your template via:

```
@routes.controllersFolder.MyControllerName.endPointName
```

This will resolve to the route.

eg routes file:

```
GET   /myApp/endpointExample  controllersFolder.MyControllerName.endPointName
```

so

```
@routes.controllersFolder.MyControllerName.endPointName
```

would resolve to:

```
/myApp/endpointExample
```

If you're looking to use that on client side for AJAX I would highly recommend [JSRoutes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting).

If you want to have the functionality of a controller then you should have it decoupled in a module eg:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}

@Singleton 
class MyClass with MyTrait

@Singleton
class MyController @Inject() (myClass: MyClass) extends Controller {
  def endPointName(x: String, y: String): Action[AnyContent] = {
    try {
      Ok(
        Json.toJson(
          Json.obj(
            "result" -> myClass.add(
              x = x.toInt,
              y = y.toInt
            )
          )
        )
      )
    } catch {
      case e: NonFatal => BadRequest(
        Json.toJson(
          Json.obj(
            "error" -> e.getMessage
          )
       )
    }
  }
}
```

You could then refer to the logic of MyClass, without having to form a request, decoupling the logic like so:

```
@Singleton
class MyOtherController @Inject() (myClass: MyClass) extends Controller {
  def myHtmlPage(): Action[AnyContent] = {
    views.html.myView(myClass)
  }
}
```

in HMTL

myView.scala.html:

```
@(myClass: MyClass)

@myClass.add(1, 2) // = 3
```

I hope this helps,
Rhys

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the controller in views, you should do it with the help of `reverse routes`

Assuming that your routes is defined like this

```
GET   /hello/:name          controllers.Application.hello(name)
```

In the views, you can call it using the following code

```
@routes.Application.hello("test")
```

Good luck with you